# Python subprocess.run CalledProcessError while running rsh

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, sigpipe, rsh

I am running a script on a remote machine as:

```
subprocess.run(
    ["rsh", self.target] + shlex.split(cmd),
    check=True
)
```

The command always runs successfully on the remote machine, but as soon as it finishes on the remote machine, I get a CalledProcessError with

```
 Command 'cmd' died with <Signals.SIGPIPE: 13>.
```

This behavior is not consistent and doesn't happen everytime (the other times the subprocess exits without any exception as expected). I'm wondering what might be the issue here, and how to fix it?